# How can I recover my reflog list so that the entire list appears in "git log" as well?

Tags: git, github, git-log

I am new to git, and I was trying to push something to my remote repository and when it did not work I reset my git and now I can see that my code is not gone, (that is my very last well-working version of my code is still there) which is a relief. But when I run "git log" it only shows the last commit. I kinda liked my history of the commits, as I move forward in my project I want to be able to have a look at all my previous codes as they evolved and progressed. So when I do "git reflog" I can see them, but when I do "git log" I can only see the last one.

So, in my case I HAVE NOT LOST anything, my last commit is there, and my code is up to date to its last version, only I cannot see the history of my commits. I want to see the history of my commits as before. that's it.

Anyone can help?

P. S. please be quick in helping me as I have read the reflog gets cleaned up every 90 days! :(

Cheers,

Comment: How is it possible that your history has disappeared?  Are you saying your current branch really only shows a single commit as its history?

Comment: Did you check the info page? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: This is what I see when I run "git reflog":                                                                                                          commit a2256194e696efd6979782b398c8fc89935c0517
Author: venesa <email>
Date:   Wed Apr 20 14:15:13 2016 +1000

    I don't know what is going on with git!

commit 842977dc565cd7bd316ed37d817d90c58b285dc6
Author: venesa <email>
Date:   Fri Apr 1 17:44:09 2016 +1100

    first commit

commit 159ec182b0c9d3bf51020b1cc4108b5e618771bd

Comment: but when I run "git log" I see this:                                                                                                                a225619 HEAD@{0}: commit: I don't know what is going on with git!
842977d HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to origin
b0d82e0 HEAD@{2}: commit: same
9b0967e HEAD@{3}: commit: Shopping cart service and directive added
84ba8bf HEAD@{4}: commit: added error promise function, simplified the markup
c09183c HEAD@{5}: commit: Edit product added
63371e5 HEAD@{6}: commit: traditional modal for addProduct failed _trying a directive
...(and so forth)

Comment: so you can see that reflog shows the entire commits list but "log" does not. I searched the comments and help, mostly they are for reverting back to a desired desired commit by first checking up its SHA1 in the list that reflog shows and then the related command for retrieving it. My problem though is just being able to see them as before by doing "git log".

Comment: And yes, the answer to your question is that it only shows the last commit that I made today when I got mixed up with git after resetting it and my very first commit named "first commit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `git reset`, you may have moved the branch label to point to a different commit (this is what `git reset` does, or more precisely, one of several things `git reset` can do<sup>1</sup>).  That is, suppose you have some commits, on a branch named `xyzbranch`, so that `xyzbranch` points to the tip-most commit, marked `*` here.  Let's further suppose that there's an `origin/xyzbranch` that points to another commit, probably an earlier one in the chain, or maybe even on a side-branch off the chain; let's mark that one with a bigger (uppercase) `O` here:

```
                         xyzbranch
                             |
                             v

... <- o <- ... <- O <- o <- *

                   ^
                   |
            origin/xyzbranch
```

Moreover, suppose you are currently on `xyzbranch` (so that `git status` says `on branch xyzbranch`).  Then, suppose you do something like:

```
$ git reset --hard origin/xyzbranch
```

This directs git to change the commit your current branch points-to, so that it points to the commit you just named.  The result looks like this:

```
               xyzbranch
                   |
                   v

... <- o <- ... <- O <- o <- *

                   ^
                   |
            origin/xyzbranch
```

Note that commit `*` is still hanging out there, even though it may be hard to find.  You are correct: it is protected by the *reflog* for `xyzbranch` and for `HEAD`.  (However, it's not 90 days, but 30 days by default.<sup>2</sup>)

The trick is to find a name for commit `*`.  Its "true name" is the SHA-1 hash, which of course is too long and crazy to type in all the time, something like `19ca3f07...dd5` or whatever.  However, if you can find that name, you can be sure you can name commit `*` by supplying that SHA-1.

Alternatively (and easier), you can look through your reflogs using `git reflog`:

```
$ git reflog
ca0bf9d HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD^
0cba526 HEAD@{1}: commit (merge): temp-commit-ugh
ca0bf9d HEAD@{2}: commit: create new file in master
... [snip]
$ git reflog dev
76c1ae2 dev@{0}: commit: create newfile in dev
696077e dev@{1}: commit: modify sub/one
... [snip]
```

(these commit messages are terrible as this is a temporary repository I was using to test certain merge cases).

The leftmost part is an abbreviated version of the hash, which is a string you can use any time.  The next part, `HEAD@{3}` or `dev@{1}` or whatever, is a *relative* index (to the name before the `@`) that tells git how deep to search in that particular reflog.  Every time you update a ref—whether that's `HEAD` (which tracks "the current branch", whatever branch that is), or a specific branch like `xyxbranch`, or in my case, branches `dev` and `master`—git adds a new reflog entry (or two, if `HEAD` names a branch, as it usually does).  This pushes all the other reflog entries down one step, so that whatever was in `HEAD@{3}` before, it is now in `HEAD@{4}` instead.

If this is what you did, and you want `xyzbranch` to point to commit `*` again, you can use `git reflog xyzbranch` to see where `xyzbranch` used to point, and what action changed it.  In my case, I did a reset on `HEAD` (which was actually master so I could see this on `master` too, but I'll just use the default `HEAD` reflog).  The action `reset: ...` shows my `git reset` command, so wherever `HEAD` pointed just before that is interesting.  You can feed either the number (here, `0cba526`) or the indexed-name (`HEAD@{1}`, here) to `git log` or `git show` to see it.

Once you have found the correct commit, you can use `git reset` to move the branch label back there.  Or, if you want to keep the branch label where it is now, you can make a *new* branch that points to the desired commit.  Let's say that I want to get `0cba526` onto a new branch.  There are two commands that do just that:

```
$ git branch newbr 0cba526
```

or, if you want git to be on `newbr`—i.e., to first create `newbr` pointing to commit `0cba526`, then also do a `git checkout newbr`:

```
$ git checkout -b newbr 0cba526
```

(note that both of these require your work tree to be clean, as it would be after an earlier `git reset --hard`).  Let's draw one last graph, which is what you would have after the `git branch newbr 0cba526` command, and this time add `HEAD` into the picture as well:

```
                 HEAD
                   |
                   v
               xyzbranch   newbr
                   |         |
                   v         v

... <- o <- ... <- O <- o <- *

                   ^
                   |
            origin/xyzbranch
```

(I believe it helps a lot if you think of git's branch labels as little yellow sticky notes that you paste onto commit IDs.  These sticky notes come off and get pasted on different commits, and this happens all the time and is entirely normal in git.  Meanwhile `HEAD` is another sticky note, usually pasted directly on top of one of the branch label sticky notes, so that you move both at the same time—but you can peel them apart and stick `HEAD` right on a commit node instead, after which `HEAD` continues to rover over commit nodes, until you use `git checkout <branch>` to peel `HEAD` off the commit nodes and paste it onto the yellow sticky note that is `<branch>`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>I firmly believe that `git reset` does *too many* things, which is part of what makes it hard to explain.  But we are stuck with that, in git.

<sup>2</sup>More precisely, reflog entries themselves expire: some expire after 30 days, and some after 90 days.  Once the reflog entry itself has expired, *then* the commits they protected are no longer protected.  The 30 day period applies to reflog entries that point to commits that are not *reachable* from the corresponding reference: that is, if this is the `master` reflog, and `master@{123}` points to commit `faded00`, and `master` points to commit `ac0ffee`, then we decide whether `master@{123}` lives now by first doing:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor faded00 ac0ffee
```

If the answer is "yes, `faded00` *is* an ancestor of `ac0ffee`" then we choose 90 days, otherwise we choose 30 days.  Then we check the date stamp for `master@{123}` and if it is too old, we throw it out, so that `master@{124}` moves down one and becomes the new `master@{123}`.

Once the reflog entry is discarded, it no longer protects the commit (which in this case is commit `faded00`).  If something *else* still protects the commit, the commit remains safe.  If *nothing* protects it, though, it may then be garbage-collected and thus finally deleted.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I followed your second suggested resolution ($ git branch newbr 0cba526) and made a new branch and it worked perfectly well. This is so cool, thank you so much for your comprehensive reply.